# Java class TLValidationJob of DSS says onlineLoader not defined, but I did it

Tags: java

I am trying the DSS Digital Signature Library 5.12.1 (https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/sites/display/DIGITAL/Digital+Signature+Service+-++DSS) to locally store the X509 certificates trusted in the EU using the class TLValidationJob.
Running the method onlineRefresh I get this unexpected exception "java.lang.NullPointerException: The onlineLoader must be defined!"

I have properly run TLValidationJob.setOnlineDataLoader and soon after I have run the method onlineRefresh.
It should put the sources/certificates info in my cache, but onlineRefresh casts the exception "Unable to retrieve the content for url 'https://ec.europa.eu/tools/lotl/eu-lotl.xml'", reason: "java.lang.NullPointerException: The onlineLoader must be defined!", how so?
This is my barebone code (some left apart):

```
private static File tlCacheDirectory() {
    return new File("./myLOTLcache");
}
public static DSSFileLoader onlineLoader() {
    FileCacheDataLoader onlineFileLoader = new FileCacheDataLoader();
    onlineFileLoader.setCacheExpirationTime(-1); // negative value means cache never expires
    onlineFileLoader.setFileCacheDirectory(tlCacheDirectory());
    return onlineFileLoader;
}
public static CacheCleaner cacheCleaner() {
    CacheCleaner cacheCleaner = new CacheCleaner();
    cacheCleaner.setCleanMemory(true); // free the space in memory
    cacheCleaner.setCleanFileSystem(true); // and the filesystem
    cacheCleaner.setDSSFileLoader(onlineLoader());
    return cacheCleaner;
}

public static LOTLSource europeanLOTLSource() {

    LOTLSource lotlSource = new LOTLSource();
    lotlSource.setUrl("https://ec.europa.eu/tools/lotl/eu-lotl.xml");
    // I know what "pivot" is here, but "pivot support"?
    lotlSource.setPivotSupport(true);
    lotlSource.setLotlPredicate(TLPredicateFactory.createEULOTLPredicate());
    lotlSource.setTlPredicate(TLPredicateFactory.createEUTLPredicate());
    return lotlSource;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TrustedListsCertificateSource myTLcertSource = new TrustedListsCertificateSource();

    TLValidationJob tlValidationJob = new TLValidationJob();
    LOTLSource mylotl = europeanLOTLSource();
    tlValidationJob.setListOfTrustedListSources(mylotl);

    // set the TrustedListsCertificateSource to be filled with the job results,
    // i.e. the list[s] should go into myTLcertSource
    tlValidationJob.setTrustedListCertificateSource(myTLcertSource);
    tlValidationJob.setOnlineDataLoader(onlineLoader());
    tlValidationJob.onlineRefresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved. I switched from the onlineLoader to the offlineLoader solution of the Digital Signature EU library (DSS) but most important I have added a proper invocation of setDataLoader.
Code snippet is:

```
public static DSSFileLoader offlineLoader() {
        FileCacheDataLoader offlineFileLoader = new FileCacheDataLoader();
        offlineFileLoader.setCacheExpirationTime(-1); // negative value means cache never expires
        offlineFileLoader.setDataLoader(new NativeHTTPDataLoader());
        offlineFileLoader.setFileCacheDirectory(tlCacheDirectory());
        return offlineFileLoader;
    }
```

and in the main method:

```
tlValidationJob.setOfflineDataLoader(offlineLoader());
tlValidationJob.offlineRefresh();
```